# Fuel gauge query

Tags: mitsubishi, galant

we have a pretty old Mitsubishi Galant and live in Thailand. I am curious as to why the fuel gauge registers quicker depending on the brand of fuel;for example when we refill at a Shell pump the gauge goes up immediately to show the tank is full. However, when we refill at any other pumps it can take quite a while to show how much is in there. Why is this?

Comment: Perhaps the forecourt slopes differently...

Comment: Perhaps it just seems that way. I have an old Ford, sometimes the gauge responds quite quickly, at other time takes a lot longer (and sometimes when I *haven't* refuelled but only started up and driven off).

Comment: I don't know about Mitsubishi's, but many Ford's fuel gages will rise very slowly if the engine is running or the key is in the run position while filling. If you turn the key off and then on the gage will rise quickly. If the key is off while you fill and turn the key on after filling, the gage will rise quickly. Is there anything different you are doing at the Shell station than the others?

Comment: Probably a result of different flow rates of dispenser pumps.